How to make a url redirection to open inside iframe Wordpress
i'm using Wordpress, i have a page which redirects to an external Url, I want to make this Url to open inside an Iframe instead of the regular redirection. i want the user to be redirected but stay in the same page by loading this Url inside an iframe. is this possible ? can i achieve it with any plugin or a custom code ?

You'd need javascript I expect. And make it not redirect, or even contact the server side at all, but simply set the URL of an iframe and add it to the page. That seems the most likely solution,  unless there is some complication we aren't aware of. We can't see your existing code so we cannot be 100% sure, of course.

Thanks for your comment, is a simple page that have an auto-redirection to an external url, i'm looking for a solution to make all external links opening in an iframe inside a page, i think that this will be a general solution but is similar to what i want, but i don't know from where to start. do you have any idea ?

Whether this will work, will first of all depend on whether that external page allows browsers to display it in (i)frames on a different domain. "but i don't know from where to start" - with a proper explanation, of what setup you currently have - because "is a simple page that have an auto-redirection to an external url" isn't really clear to begin with. What does this mean; how was this redirect set up in the first place?

Ok. I don't really know how specifc is your case.
If you want some link that opens an external site (of another origin) into a specific <iframe>, then you just need add the name attribute to your frame, then add the target attribute to the link anchor (<a>) with the name you defined your frame with.
Run the following snippet to see it working:


iframe
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>
<div>
  <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="myFrame">CLICK HERE</a>
</div>



PS.: I don't know why the frame is refusing to load the link though.

Thanks, i think this will work with a button to target an ifram, in my case there is an auto redirection i think, is better if i can find a solution that will make all redirection to external links that happen on my site to be opened inside an iframe, do you have any idea ?

@KamalCherkaoui, yes. You can actually put <base target="myFrame" /> inside the <head> tag. This will make all <a> without a target attribute to load inside the frame named myFrame (you can change this). If no frame or window exits with the name myFrame, then a new window/tab named myFrame will be open.
